# Split up single cell into multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to achieve as shown in the screenshot above? So in the first screenshot, the data is all in cell `A1` with line breaks. I would like for it to break down and follow the format as shown in screenshot 2? Any help would be greatly appreciated... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the linefeed to split the string into a `Variant` which becomes an array.
Cycle through the array and use the array's current position to populate a column:

```
Sub splitter()
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Long
    x = Split(Range("A1").Value2, vbLf)
    For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value2 = x(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want you could populate a range directly with your array. No need to loop

Answer (score 1):

As JvdV mentioned in his comment you do not need a loop for this

```
Sub SplitterA()

Dim x As Variant
    x = Split(Range("A1").Value2, vbLf)
    Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(x) + 1).Value2 = x

End Sub
```